# Website Unavailable on Mobile Browsers

Tags: vpn, firewall, mobile-devices

I have a web app running on apache tomcat 7.0.69 that is only accessible on an internal network via VPN.  If I try to reach the site on VPN enabled laptop/desktop computer, everything works fine.  However, if I try to access the site on VPN enabled mobile device (ipad, iphone, android etc...), I see a server not found error.

If I try to access other internal sites on the mobile devices, they all work fine, so I think that the problem is with my site specifically.

I am struggling with how to troubleshoot this issue.  Is it possible that our IT set up a firewall for this site for the mobile browsers specifically?  Could there be a blocked port on my server that is not accessible to mobile browsers?

Any advice on things to try would be much appreciated.

EDIT:  Here are the exact error messages:

iPad: 'Safari cannot open the page because the server cannot be found.'

iPhone: 'Safari cannot open the page because the server cannot be found.'

Samsung:  This one is apparently not on the VPN, working on this then I will update with error.

Comment: It's possible that different devices get treated differently on your VPN. Can you share the exact error message you're getting from your browser?

Comment: Added errors as edit in original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is certainly possible that a firewall rule may block clients differently.  There are many possibilities though so you need to collate more information. To troubleshoot this you might first find answers to the following questions:

Do you access the site via name or IP address?

Is your server on the same subnet as other servers that do work?

Does mobile VPN enter via the same tunnel server and using the same profile as laptop?

Are you expected to add extra routes to your host to reach different clients?

Answer (score 0):

Run your web site against SSLlabs.com and ensure that it has the minimum TLS/SSL settings for mobile browser.